# Inheritance with separate tables and LEFT JOIN: how to know which subclass the record belongs to

Tags: mysql, inheritance

I am trying to implement inheritance with separate tables like this:

```
Animal (id, name, age)
Cat (id_animal, other fields related to cats)
Dog (id_animal, other fields related to dogs)
```

where `id_animal` references `animal.id`.

I wonder what is the best way to get all the data about a record given its `id`.
For now I have this query:

```
SELECT * FROM animal
LEFT JOIN cat ON cat.id_animal = animal.id
LEFT JOIN dog ON dog.id_animal = animal.id
WHERE animal.id = 5
```

I get all the data I need... but I don't know if the animal `5` is a cat or a dog. In fact I have several inherited tables with the sames attributes *for the moment* and so I cannot get the type of the animal by testing the NULL columns in the response.

I also fear that all these JOINs will slow down my application.

So what is the best solution?

1. Add a `type` column in `Animal` (and perhaps get the type with a first `SELECT` and get the subclass-related fields with another `SELECT` on the corresponding subtable?)
2. other

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to do this, but as an intellectual exercise... Your "add a type column" sounds the way I would handle it; though I might add a "type" table with a field that specifies which table holds the additional details for that type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, your query is fine and it won't be super slow (considering that you added index, and you don't really have a super big table). 'Type' can be generated in the following way. You don't have to have a column for it.

```
SELECT *, 
    IF(cat.id_animal IS NOT NULL, 'CAT', IF(dog.id_animal IS NOT NULL, 'DOG', 'NEITHER')) 
FROM animal
LEFT JOIN cat ON cat.id_animal = animal.id
LEFT JOIN dog ON dog.id_animal = animal.id
WHERE animal.id = 5
```

Right now, the result table will have quite a lot of NULL entries. Another way you could do as follow:

```
SELECT animal.*, 'CAT' type, concat(cat.col1, cat.col2, ...) detail 
FROM animal
JOIN cat ON cat.id_animal = animal.id
WHERE animal.id = 5
UNION
SELECT animal.*, 'DOG' type, concat(dog.col1, dog.col2, ...) detail 
FROM animal
JOIN dog ON dog.id_animal = animal.id
WHERE animal.id = 5
```